# Calling MSVC builtin/intrinsics for C math functions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, intrinsics, built-in

For GCC and Clang, I can easily do this:

```
    // absolute value
    inline constexpr int abs(const int number)
    { return __builtin_abs(number); }
    inline constexpr long abs(const long number)
    { return __builtin_labs(number); }
    inline constexpr long long abs(const long long number)
    { return __builtin_llabs(number); }
    inline constexpr double abs(const double& number)
    { return __builtin_fabs(number); }
    inline constexpr float abs(const float& number)
    { return __builtin_fabsf(number); }
    inline constexpr long double abs(const long double& number)
    { return __builtin_fabsl(number); }
```

Which works like a charm. I'd like to do a similar thing for pretty much every math function, and have my code work on MSVC as well. How can I do the equivalent of the above for MSVC?

**EDIT**: for clarity: the question is about the `__builtin_*` functions, nothing else. I tried

```
#pragma intrinsic(abs)
```

but this needs a declaration of the abs function, which I would like not to have in my global namespace.

Comment: There is a response to this that links to the available intrinsics in MSVC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355967/how-to-use-msvc-intrinsics-to-get-the-equivalent-of-this-gcc-code

Comment: Are you asking if `constexpr` is supported in Microsoft's compiler? The answer is no, not for Visual Studio 2010 or the next version, VS 11.

Comment: IIRC you shouldn't need to even do this - I believe there's a compiler switch that determines whether the built-ins are used instead of library functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intrinsic functions are not portable, so you'll have to manually [look up the corresponding builtin function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5405h95.aspx) and add it to the list, and use `#ifdef` to switch modes.

You don't have to have to have `abs` in the global namespace, by the way: include `<cstdlib>` instead of `<stdlib.h>` and [you will get `std::abs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) instead.

Compilers know what their own intrinsics are, MSVC uses [the /Oi switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f99tchzc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to enable them.