# Integer Compression Library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use this library https://github.com/lemire/SIMDCompressionAndIntersection/ with Visual Studio 2012 but I am getting a few compilation errors.

Headers `#include <sys/resource.h>` `#include <sys/time.h>` and `#include <sys/mman.h>` doesn't exist. I can simply remove them.

After this I am getting errors in many lines which have this format:

```
__attribute__((const))
inline uint32_t gccbits(const uint32_t v) {
    return v == 0 ? 0 : 32 - __builtin_clz(v);
}

missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Does anyone know how to use this library with Visual Studio 2012?

**edit: I am compiling this in G++. In terminal I type `make example` and then `./example`. I get a segfault before any output. Anyone know what is wrong?**

Comment: `__attribute__((const))` is for gcc only. Remove it for MSVC. Although I suspect you will get more errors. like `__builtin_clz`

Comment: Also the `uint32_t` typedefs needs to include `stdint.h`.

Comment: @drescherjm: Thnaks. Now I am getting not found on `__builtin_clz` and `__asm__`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/355967/487892

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you mean `<cstdint>`, since the question is tagged `c++`

Comment: @CoffeeandCode No I meant what I wrote. Using `cstdint` would require to write `std::uint32_t`  IIRC.

Comment: Also this line gives an error: `void __fastunpack0(const uint32_t   *__restrict__ in, uint32_t   *__restrict__  out);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ in theory, yeah; in practice, you can usually unsafely not write `std::`. But that's a pretty lazy excuse not to use `cstdint` when you gotta port the code anyway.

Comment: `edit: I am compiling this in G++. In terminal I type make example and then ./example. I get a segfault before any output. Anyone know what is wrong?` Start a new question about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Requirements](https://github.com/lemire/SIMDCompressionAndIntersection/#requirements) section:

> A recent GCC (4.7 or better), Clang or Intel compiler.
>
> ...
>
> Tested on Linux and MacOS. It should be portable to Windows and other
>   platforms.

Good luck with your port.