# VS: unexpected optimization behavior with _BitScanReverse64 intrinsic

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization, x86-64, intrinsics

The following code works fine in debug mode, since _BitScanReverse64 is defined 
to return 0 if no Bit is set. [Citing MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd): 
(The return value is) "Nonzero if Index was set, or 0 if no set bits were found."

If I compile this code in release mode it still works, but if I enable compiler 
optimizations, such as \O1 or \O2 the index is not zero and the `assert()` fails.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unsigned long index = 0;
  _BitScanReverse64(&index, 0x0ull);

  cout << index << endl;

  assert(index == 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Is this the intended behaviour ? I am using Visual Studio Community 2015, Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3. (I left cout in, so that the variable index is not deleted during optimization). Also is there an efficient workaround or should I just not use this compiler intrinsic directly?

Comment: Initializing index right away doesnt make a difference here, since _BitScanReverse does the initialization.

Comment: By saying "the program crashes" you mean the `assert` fails, right? It's been a while since I've used VS, but shouldn't the `assert` be disabled on release builds?

Comment: Yes, the assert fails. I think it should, but it somehow isn't :D I tried it without the assertion too and the index is still not zero

Comment: Microsoft's page on _BitScanReverse64 does not say that `index` will be set if no bit is set; it only says `index` will be set with a value if a bit is set. So, if no bit is set, _BitScanReverse64 could just be leaving `index` alone and it's left with whatever it originally had.

Comment: I have cited MSDN. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd which page are you referring to?

Comment: @Altainia has the right answer imo. You should check the return value of `_BitScanReverse64`. If it's zero, the value of `index` is undefined (at least in the docs). Assuming so because only a non-zero return indicates `index` was set.

Comment: Ok, that is strange. Can you give me a link, so I can see it for myself?

Comment: And why does it never fail when I dont optimize?

Comment: @Altainia But `index` is set to `0` now.

Comment: `index` is initialized to 0, but `_BitScanReverse64` might be changing it internally. The unoptimized version is possibly setting `index` to zero if no 1 is found, but the optimized version omits that part to save time. Both are in line with the docs (_"Nonzero if Index was set, or 0 if no set bits were found."_) and the optimized version does less hence is faster.

Comment: If the optimized version would omit the initialization of index, why is it not zero afterwards? And why is the faster version still in line with the documentation if index is 3193563 afterwards? And why is it always a quasi random number? Sorry, I still dont get it :(

Comment: Oh, I think I got it!, Thank you, eran and Altainia!

Comment: Good. @Altainia, care to make your comment a proper answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAICT, **the intrinsic leaves garbage in `index` when the input is zero,** weaker than the behaviour of the asm instruction.   This is why it has a separate boolean return value and integer output operand.

Despite the `index` arg being taken by reference, the compiler treats it as output-only.

---

`unsigned char _BitScanReverse64 (unsigned __int32* index, unsigned __int64 mask)`
[Intel's intrinsics guide documentation for the same intrinsic](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=bsr&expand=375) seems clearer than the [Microsoft docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd) you linked, and sheds some light on what the MS docs are trying to say.  But on careful reading, they do both seem to say the same thing, and describe a thin wrapper around the `bsr` instruction.

**[Intel documents the `BSR` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BSR.html) as producing an "undefined value" when the input is 0, but setting the ZF in that case.**  But AMD documents it as leaving the destination unchanged:

> [AMD's BSF entry](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24594.pdf#page=151) in *AMD64 Architecture
>   Programmer’s Manual
>   Volume 3:
>   General-Purpose and
>   System Instructions*
>
> ... If the second operand contains 0, the instruction sets ZF
>   to 1 and does not change the contents of the destination register. ...

On current Intel hardware, the actual behaviour matches AMD's documentation: it leaves the destination register unmodified when the src operand is 0.  Perhaps this is why MS describes it as only setting `Index` when the input is non-zero (and the intrinsic's return value is non-zero).

On Intel ([but maybe not AMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54379076/amd-and-intel-programmers-model-compatibility)), this goes as far as not even truncating a 64-bit register to 32-bit.  e.g. `mov rax,-1` ; `bsf eax, ecx` (with zeroed ECX) leaves RAX=-1 (64-bit), not the `0x00000000ffffffff` you'd get from `xor eax, 0`.  But with non-zero ECX, `bsf eax, ecx` has the usual effect of zero-extending into RAX, leaving for example RAX=3.

---

**IDK why Intel still hasn't documented it.**  Perhaps a really old x86 CPU (like original 386?) implements it differently?  Intel and AMD frequently [go above and beyond what's documented in the x86 manuals in order to not break existing widely-used code (e.g. Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18388700/224132), which might be how this started.

At this point it seems unlikely that Intel will ever drop that output dependency and leave actual garbage or -1 or 32 for input=0, but the lack of documentation leaves that option open.

Skylake dropped the false dependency for `lzcnt` and `tzcnt` (and a later uarch dropped the false dep for `popcnt`) while still preserving the dependency for `bsr`/`bsf`.  ([Why does breaking the "output dependency" of LZCNT matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390165/why-does-breaking-the-output-dependency-of-lzcnt-matter))

---

Of course, since **MSVC optimized away your `index = 0` initialization, presumably it just uses whatever destination register it wants, not necessarily the register that held the previous value of the C variable.**    So even if you wanted to, I don't think you could take advantage of the dst-unmodified behaviour even though it's guaranteed on AMD.

**So in C++ terms, the intrinsic has no input dependency on `index`**.  But in asm, the instruction *does* have an input dependency on the dst register, like an `add dst, src` instruction.  This can cause unexpected performance issues if compilers aren't careful.

Unfortunately on Intel hardware, the [`popcnt / lzcnt / tzcnt` asm instructions also have a false dependency on their destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078285/replacing-a-32-bit-loop-count-variable-with-64-bit-introduces-crazy-performance), even though the result never depends on it.  Compilers work around this now that it's known, though, so you don't have to worry about it when using intrinsics (unless you have a compiler more than a couple years old, since it was only recently discovered).

---

You need to check it to make sure `index` is valid, unless you know the input was non-zero.  e.g.

```
if(_BitScanReverse64(&idx, input)) {
    // idx is valid.
    // (MS docs say "Index was set")
} else {
    // input was zero, idx holds garbage.
    // (MS docs don't say Index was even set)
    idx = -1;     // might make sense, one lower than the result for bsr(1)
}
```

---

If you want to avoid this extra check branch, you can use the [`lzcnt` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LZCNT.html) via different intrinsics if you're targeting new enough hardware (e.g. Intel Haswell or AMD Bulldozer IIRC).  It "works" even when the input is all-zero, and actually counts leading zeros instead of returning the index of the highest set bit.

Comment: The reason people say it is semi-documented is because AMD documents it. See [here](https://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24594.pdf), p. 112 (p 148 in the PDF). (I can't find an x86-32 manual from AMD, but I'd swear it said something similar.)

Comment: Aside from that, your speculations about how the intrinsic works in MSVC are precisely correct. I've spent quite a bit of time playing with it, [discovered a few bugs (only for 32-bit builds)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3101349/bitscanforward-intrinsic-always-results-in-generation-of-pointless-store-to-memory), and tried to figure out ways to take advantage of the "semi-documented" behavior. Unfortunately, there is no way other than inline asm. Also, you should beware that sub-optimal code generation is possible if you do not check the intrinsic's return value!

Comment: Unfortunately, even the latest version of MSVC (VS 2015 Update 3) doesn't work around the false dependency in popcnt/lzcnt/tzcnt when you use the corresponding intrinsics. Haven't filed a bug/feature-request for that yet. They have ignored all of the bugs I've submitted so far.

Comment: @CodyGray: gcc works around the false dep for popcnt/lzcnt/tzcnt, but not for bsf/bsr.  /facepalm. :(  I'm in the middle of typing up a bug report for that.  Thanks for the links, especially to AMD's docs.