# How can a literal 0 and 0 as a variable yield different behavior with the function __builtin_clz?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, undefined-behavior, intrinsics

There's only 1 circumstance where `__builtin_clz` gives the wrong answer. I'm curious what's causing that behavior.

When I use the literal value 0 I always get 32 as expected. But 0 as a variable yields 31. Why does the method of storing the value 0 matter?

I've taken an architecture class but don't understand the diffed assembly. It looks like when given the literal value 0, the assembly somehow always has the correct answer of 32 hard coded even without optimizations. And the method for counting leading zeros is different when using -march=native.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589096/find-most-significant-bit-left-most-that-is-set-in-a-bit-array) about emulating `__builtin_clz` with `_BitScanReverse` and  the line `bsrl    %eax, %eax` seem to imply that bit scan reverse doesn't work for 0.

```
+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
|      Compile      | literal.cpp | variable.cpp |
+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
| g++               |          32 |           31 |
| g++ -O            |          32 |           32 |
| g++ -march=native |          32 |           32 |
+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

### literal.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << __builtin_clz(0) << std::endl;
}
```

### variable.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << __builtin_clz(i) << std::endl;
}
```

### Diff for g++ -S [in name] -o [out name]

```
1c1
<       .file   "literal.cpp"
---
>       .file   "variable.cpp"
23c23,26
<       movl    $32, %esi
---
>       movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
>       bsrl    %eax, %eax
>       xorl    $31, %eax
>       movl    %eax, %esi
```

### Diff for g++ -march=native -S [in name] -o [out name]

```
1c1
<       .file   "literal.cpp"
---
>       .file   "variable.cpp"
23c23,25
<       movl    $32, %esi
---
>       movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
>       lzcntl  %eax, %eax
>       movl    %eax, %esi
```

### Diff for g++ -O -S [in name] -o [out name]

```
1c1
<       .file   "literal.cpp"
---
>       .file   "variable.cpp"
```

Comment: @Matt Undefined Behavior means all bets are off. Anything can happen. Surprising and unexpected results mean nothing.

Comment: Note that `bsrl %eax,%eax` *does* work for `eax=0`, but the result is leaving the destination register unmodified and setting `ZF` based on the *input* being zero.  This is [why `bsr` has a false dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390165/why-does-breaking-the-output-dependency-of-lzcnt-matter).  AMD documents the dst-unmodified behaviour that both Intel and AMD implement, but Intel doesn't; they say the output register's value is arbitrary.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bsr.  (But not like C++ UB; it doesn't lead to unpredictable behaviour for surrounding instructions.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you compile with optimization disabled, the compiler doesn't do constant-propagation across statements. That part is a duplicate of [Why does integer division by -1 (negative one) result in FPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46378104) - read my answer there, and/or [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point)

**This is why a literal zero can be different from a variable with value = 0.** 
 Only the variable with optimization disabled results in runtime `bsr+xor $31, %reg`.

---

As documented [in the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) for `__builtin_clz`

> Returns the number of leading 0-bits in x, starting at the most significant bit position. **If `x` is 0, the result is undefined.**

This allows `clz` / `ctz` to compile to 31-`bsr` or `bsf` instructions respectively, on x86.  `31-bsr` is implemented with `bsr`+`xor $31,%reg` thanks to the magic of 2's complement.  (BSR produces the index of the highest set bit, not the leading-zero count).

**Note that it only says *result*, not *behaviour*.  It's not C++ UB** (whole program could do absolutely anything), it's limited to that result, just like in x86 asm.  But anyway, it seems when the input is a compile-time constant 0, GCC produces the type-width like x86 `lzcnt`, and like `clz` instructions on other ISAs.  (This probably happens in target-independent GIMPLE tree optimization where constant-propagation through operations including builtins is done.)

---

Intel documents [`bsf`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bsf)/[`bsr`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bsr) as *If the content source operand is 0, the content of the destination operand is undefined.*  In real life, Intel hardware implements the same behaviour AMD documents: leave the destination unmodified in that case.

But since Intel refuses to document it, compilers won't let you make code which takes advantage of it.  GCC does not know or care about that behaviour, and provides no way to take advantage of it.  Neither does MSVC even though its intrinsic that takes an output pointer arg so could easily have worked that way.  See [VS: unexpected optimization behavior with _BitScanReverse64 intrinsic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351564/vs-unexpected-optimization-behavior-with-bitscanreverse64-intrinsic/41352456#41352456)

---

**With `-march=native`, GCC can use BMI1 [`lzcnt`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lzcnt) directly, which is well-defined for every possible input bit pattern including `0`**.  It directly produces a leading-zero count instead of the *index* of the first set bit.

(This is why BSR/BSF don't make sense for input=0; there is no index for them to find.  Fun fact: `bsr %eax, %eax` does "work" for `eax=0`.  In asm, the instructions also set ZF according to whether the input was zero so you can detect when the output is "undefined" instead of a separate test+branch before `bsr`.  Or on AMD and everything else in real life, that it left the destination unmodified.)

---

### Further reading about bsf vs. lzcnt and false dependencies

On Intel until Skylake, `lzcnt` / `tzcnt` have a false dependency on the output register even though the result does *not* depend on it ever.  IIRC, Coffee Lake also fixed the false dep for `popcnt`.  (All of which runs on the same execution unit as BSR/BSF.)

- [Why does breaking the "output dependency" of LZCNT matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390165/why-does-breaking-the-output-dependency-of-lzcnt-matter)
- [VS: unexpected optimization behavior with _BitScanReverse64 intrinsic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351564/vs-unexpected-optimization-behavior-with-bitscanreverse64-intrinsic/41352456#41352456)
- [How can x86 bsr/bsf have fixed latency, not data dependent? Doesn't it loop over bits like the pseudocode shows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509623/how-can-x86-bsr-bsf-have-fixed-latency-not-data-dependent-doesnt-it-loop-over)